# In pyspark how to check the format a pyspark was read in? Delta vs parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have function that reads in file which could either be in delta or parquet format.

```
def getData(filename,fileFormat)
      if data_format == "parquet":
        return spark.read.parquet(filename)
      elif data_format == "delta":
        return spark.read.format("delta").load(filename)
```

I then use the returned pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in some analysis function

```
def someAnalyticalFunction(df)
  if df == "parquet":  #I know this isnt right but how do i check the data format?
     #do some analysis
  elif df == "delta"
     #do some slight different analysis
```

Is there away that i can check in the analysis function, what format the dataframe (df) the was read in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with Spark, but you can use `dbutils.fs` to check if delta metadata file exists

Comment: Amazing thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the isDeltaTable method from the Delta Lake API.

- https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html
- https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.isDeltaTable

```py
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

def check_format(spark: SparkSession, path: str) -> str:
    """ Return the format of the spark path """
    if DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, path):
        return "delta"

    else:
        return "parquet"
```